# Collect an email address in survey then submit to that email address for approval

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, survey

Just getting started into SharePoint 2010 in work and wondering if something like this is possible.

Firstly, 2 groups of people are using a survey:

Group 1 - Contribute access

Group 2 - Approve access

Member of group 1 completes survey, but 1 question in the survey asks for their bosses email. When the survey is finished, it is emailed to the email address that they added.

Member of group 2 receives the survey, answers some additional questions and completes approval.

I'm having trouble seeing if this can be done thorough a workflow or some other method as I've only just recently started with sharepoint so I'm still working out what is an isn't possible with it

Comment: So group 2 is made up of the bosses group 1 reports to?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an easy way to do this out-of-the-box that would keep the group 1 user from filling out the additional questions, and keep all of the information in one list. You could use the "Collect Feedback" workflow to get the additional information from the group 2 user. Or you could use "Create List Item" workflow step to copy the information into another list that has the additional questions for group 2, and emails the group 2 user a link to fill out the rest of the item in the second list.

Or, it's a bit  advanced, but you could create a custom form in SharePoint Designer that has a security-trimmed section for those with Approve access.

If you can use third party tools, InfoWise Smart List will let you set permissions on specific fields.

Regardless of the approach used, I would probably use a People field and have the group 1 user select their boss from there rather than manually entering their boss's email. I can give you more details on any of these approaches, if any of them sound like they'd work for you.